# Latex formatting entire document for spacing after full stop and comma

Tags: formatting

I am writing a long document in latex. I want to make sure that through out the document the following thing is maintained:

1. no space before and one space after "." (full stop) at the end of a sentence.
2. no space before and one space after "," (comma).

This should be done irrespective of how ever the text is written in the latex editor.

I tried using \frenchspacing but that does not do this properly. If i have multiple space after "." it reduces it to one space. but if there is no space after "." it does not add a space there.

I am not sure if this can be done or not! please help...

Example : I want **this. I** want this.

I don't want **this.I** don't want this.

Comment: If the document is mostly text an usual search and replace could help. By the way, you must be sure there are no decimal numbers in the document, like `2.2` or `2,1`, or something like “versions” like `Version 3.2.12`. I think it would be more secure to write correctly rather than ask LaTeX to save you.

Comment: It is possible to attempt this but is very fragile and likely to break many other constructs. the space after a `.` is no different to the space between words: if you want a space place one in the source, if you want no space do not put one.

Comment: I think it's better to ask your editor to do this job. Some can do it (probably Emacs, and I'm sure WinEdt on windows can. As for the problem of decimal numbers, you can use the numprint package.